# add time (char(8)) to date column

Tags: oracle, datetime, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, date-formatting

i try to merge a date and time column.

```
CREATE TABLE teldat(
    date    DATE,
    uhrzeit     CHAR(8),
    time        CHAR(8),
    teilnehmer  NUMBER(3),
    verbart     NUMBER(1),
    aufbauart   CHAR(3),
    ziel        VARCHAR(15));

alter table teldat add (date_conv date);

INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('04.08.2011'),'17:33 ', '00:00:40',10,9, 'K10', NULL); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('04.08.2011'),'18:50 ', '00:01:41',13,9, 'K10', NULL); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('04.08.2011'),'19:10 ', '00:02:17',21,1, 'G1 ', '01019012896****'); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('04.08.2011'),'19:31 ', '00:11:01',10,9, 'K10', NULL); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('04.08.2011'),'19:52 ', '00:09:47',20,1, 'G11', '077202****'); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('04.08.2011'),'19:49 ', '10:07:02',21,1, 'G1 ', '01019012896****'); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('04.08.2011'),'19:58 ', '00:02:41',21,1, 'G1 ', '01019012896****'); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('04.08.2011'),'20:01 ', '00:02:31',21,1, 'G1 ', '01019012896****'); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('05.08.2011'),'09:03 ', '00:03:02',11,9, 'K10', NULL); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('05.08.2011'),'09:13 ', '00:03:31',10,1, 'G10', '071174****'); 
INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('05.08.2011'),'09:39 ', '00:06:45',13,1, 'G10', '0711707*****');

update teldat set date_conv=(to_date(substr(date, 1, 2)+substr(date, 4, 2)+substr(date, 6, 2)+substr(time, 1, 2)+substr(time, 4, 2),'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi'));
```

if i execute the update statement, the following error message appears:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
update teldat set date_conv=(to_date(substr(date, 1, 2)+substr(date, 4, 2)+substr(date, 6, 2)+substr(time, 1, 2)+substr(time, 4, 2),'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi'))
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 45
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:  *Action:
```

come to no solution. can anyone help me?

Kind Regards

Comment: You should not store times values or durations as string. `DATE` data type also contains a time part, you can use this. For duration, Oracle provides [INTERVAL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i38598) data types.

Comment: DATE data type also contains a time part <- i try to merge date and time field to a single column. i updated the error message on main thread.

Comment: I'm no Oracle expert but shouldn't there be a space between your year and the time?  substr(date, 6, 2) + substr(time, 1, 2)+

Answer (score 0):

This update works:

```
update teldat set 
  date_conv = to_date(to_char(tdate, 'yyyymmdd')||uhrzeit,'yyyymmddhh24:mi');
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ce980/1)</sup>

I assumed that you want second column (uhrzeit) for time part, but if you want next column - use it (with substr(..., 5)). Also I changed column name `date` to `tdate` because `date` is Oracle keyword, so it's better to avoid using it as column name.

Comment: i only get the date in the date_conv raw if i execute your command :/?

update teldat set datum_conv = to_date(to_char(datum, 'dd.mm.yyyy')||to_char(uhrzeit,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'));

i tried this also...

Comment: But why are you changing anything? Just run this update as is - it works indepenently from date format settings, you can see this in the SQLFiddle. Only thing you need to change is column name - `datum` instead of `tdate`.

Comment: "I only get the date" - how are you displaying the value? Maybe you're relying on NLS_DATE_FORMAT that doesn't include the time? Yours seems to be set to DD.MM.YYYY. Try displaying it with a full date format model that includes the time.

Comment: ah ok now i understand whats wrong. 
i entered select * from teldat, but there was no time specification shown in the date_conv. Did you know the reason? i am still a rookie^^after that i tried your select command on fiddle - works fine!

Comment: You can change how to display dates in your client program - in SQLDeveloper it is in menu: Tools-Preferences-Database-NLS-Date format.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make the below corrections and try:

1. Change the column name from date to dates(any name) as `DATE` is an oracle Keyword
2. The no of values you are inserting is 7 which less than the columns you have in the table after altering(adding) 1 column (7+1 = 8). Hence add one more value.
3. Correct the update statement(see below)

> alter SESSION set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ;

```
CREATE TABLE teldat(
    dates   DATE,
    uhrzeit     CHAR(8),
    time        CHAR(8),
    teilnehmer  NUMBER(3),
    verbart     NUMBER(1),
    aufbauart   CHAR(3),
    ziel        VARCHAR(15));

alter table teldat add (date_conv date);

INSERT INTO TELDAT VALUES (to_date('04.08.2011','dd.mm.yyyy'),'17:33 ', '00:00:40',10,9, 'K10', NULL,
to_date('13.08.2011','dd.mm.yyyy'));

select* from teldat;

update teldat  set date_conv= 
TO_DATE(
 substr(dates, 1, 2) || '-'  || 
 substr(dates, 4, 3) || '-'  ||
 substr(dates, 8, 4) || '-'  || 
 substr(time, 1, 2) || ':'   ||
 substr(time, 4, 2) 
 ,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
; 

commit;
```

> OUTPUT:

[image: OUTPUT]

Answer (score 0):

SQLDeveloper Menu: Tools, Preferences, Database, change NLS-Date format

```
update teldat set datum_conv=to_date(to_char(datum, 'dd.mm.yyyy')||uhrzeit,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi');
select to_char(datum_conv, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from teldat ;
```

Works for me!
Thanks for all the help guys!! :)

Kind Regards